# Conver a stateLessWidget to function

Tags: flutter, firebase, function, class, dart

I'm a new flutter developer.
I have a code to read data from firebase for one time

this code:

```
class GetUserName extends StatelessWidget {
  final String documentId;

  GetUserName(this.documentId);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: users.doc(documentId).get(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("Something went wrong");
        }

        if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
          return Text("Document does not exist");
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return Text("Full Name: ${data['full_name']} ${data['last_name']}");
        }

        return Text("loading");
      },
    );
  }
}
```

it's work fine but I want to put these method into my Provider as function like this

```
Future<DocumentSnapshot> getUserName(String uid) => _database.doc(uid).snapshots();
```

so I want to put a function into provider class when I call this function it return a field data of this documents... (Replace GetUserName class as shown app, to be a function method only)

so how to write this function and how to call it as a map of data?

---

Edit:

as shown in this image:

[image]

here I got data as StreamBuilder and its work fine

here the explained method for stream in my provider class

[image]

[image]

as shown in the Following Image

[image]

```
Map<String, dynamic> data
```

I use data like

data['username']

it works fine so I want to put in My Provider class a function and returns a String, has two parameters for Example:

Text(myfunction(uid, value));
and it returns a string from (uid),
value = data[value]

Comment: you like to return value from this widet?

Comment: I want to put a method in my Provider class and when I call method it returns data such as my stateLessWidget but not to return as widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add it before return HomePage();

```
auth.userData = data;
return HomePage();
```

add it in Auth provider

```
class Auth implements AuthBase {
    Map<String,dynamic>? userData;
    String  getUserName(String parameter) {
    return userData![parameter].toString(); 
    }

}
```

Comment: he method 'data' isn't defined for the type 'Future'. (Documentation)  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'data'.

Comment: Map<String, dynamic> data  = (await users.doc(documentId).get()).data();

Comment: A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.

Comment: just as Map<String, dynamic>;

Comment: Text('${auth.getUserName('${auth.currentUser?.uid}')}')  ==== I try use this , Resualt: Intance of Future<String>

Comment: it give me this resualt , Instance of 'Future<String>'

Comment: you can't use it this.

Comment: so what the solution

Comment: check new update

Comment: thanks ,but it isn't  return data , I thinks my problem not solution like this

Comment: it miss return. try again.previous version it show "Loading" always?

Comment: yes it show Loading only

Comment: try new update. sorry for missing return

Comment: yor code returns 'return Text("loading");' is return a widget I need my method to return data only

Comment: auth.getUserName('${auth.currentUser?.uid}') is a data. FutureBuilder just a widget to show that data. and when you want to get data only just call String data = await auth.getUserName('${auth.currentUser?.uid}') in async function

Comment: I mean my project is check only from document field if is true then return a screen

Comment: I will update my post with Iamges wait a second

Comment: is new solution work?

Comment: your solution also need to use build,, see my update with image

Comment: What do you want with it? something like you want to check your user state, if that user isLogin then go to HOME or user logout go to LOGIN page?

Comment: yes I have no problem with this.. but every time I want to reach the data I use StreamBuilder

Comment: I want to put method in provider , and return data every time like a stream builder

Comment: when I use StreamBuilder as you see I listen to only one uid in document , I want a method because to reach another document without streambuilder

Comment: just set your Map<String, dynamic> data to provider. and when you want to get value then call data['id'] data['value'] or something

Comment: @override
  Future<String> getUserName(String uid, String parameter) async {
    CollectionReference users = _database;
    DocumentSnapshot data = users.doc(uid).get() as DocumentSnapshot<Object?>;
    Map<String, dynamic> resualt = data.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    
    return resualt[parameter].toString();
  }

Comment: I try this but resault is : instance of 'Future<String>'

Comment: auth.userData = data;
return HomePage();
String  getUserName(String parameter) {
return userData[parameter].toString(); }

Comment: same problem ::: Text('${auth.getUserName('name1', 'username')}'); the result is (Instance of 'Future<String>'

Comment: String getUserName(String parameter) { return userData[parameter].toString(); } can't show 'Future<String>'

Comment: I didn't understand where should put your code

Comment: in Auth provider, it a function of provider, replace for old function"Future<String> getUserName..."

Comment: type 'Future<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>' is not a subtype of type 'DocumentSnapshot<Object?>' in type cast

Comment: DocumentSnapshot data = users.doc(uid).get() as DocumentSnapshot<Object?>;

Comment: this by editor give me this solution

Comment: String getUserName(String uid, String parameter) {
    CollectionReference users = _database;
    DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> data = users.doc(uid).get() as DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>;
    Map<String, dynamic> resualt = data.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return resualt[parameter].toString();
  }

Comment: Do you use facebook

Comment: Check your mess